# Use Javascript Regular Expression to categorize my objects

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array for objects returned from a specific API.One of the property of the obejcts received is 'Serial No' which can have values like 1 , 1.1 , 1.1.2 and so on.Please note that this could go up to anything like 17 , 17.1 , 17.1.12 etc.

My problem is to seperate these into one of the 3 groups

- number with no decimal       Ex: **1** ,   **2**    , **13**    etc
- number with 1 decimal points       Ex: **1.1** , **2.19** , **12.11** etc
- number with 2 decimal points       Ex: **1.1.3** , **2.1.10** , **10.11.4** etc

I believe the best way to go about is by using javascript regular expression to segregate into one of the 3 categories.Please suggest ?

Comment: Do you care about the actual version numbers themselves at this point (ie do you want to extract them) or is simply finding out to which group they belong the sole requirement?

Comment: show that "array for objects"

Comment: can you share your input data-structure?

Answer (score 1):

Nah. Split should be good to help you figure out the category

```
serialno.split('.').length
```

Will tell you how many numbers separated by . you have

How did you need the output?

Comment: @bikash Accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "1.1.3";
var dots_count = s.match(/\./g) || []).length;
if (dots_count === 0) {
  console.log('group like 1')
} else if (dots_count === 1){
  console.log('group like 1.1')
} else if (dots_count === 2){
  console.log('group like 1.1.1')
}
```